# Use colours from resources

Tags: c#, maui

Im trying to access the colours inside my resources file in a Content page located in another file, is this possible at all?
Thanks in advance!

Resources/Styles/Colors.Xaml

```
 <Color x:Key="Primary">#512BD4</Color>
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;



namespace UniVerse
{
    public class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" ,
                        TextColor = //Add Color here
                        
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Search [maui use resource in c#](https://www.google.com/search?q=maui+use+resource+in+c%23) finds https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries. See section "Access resources by key from code".

Answer (score 1):

As Steve has suggested that you can access resources by key from code behind, the following example shows how to retrieve and apply a resource from a page's resource dictionary:

```
// Retrieve the Primary color value which is in the page's resource dictionary
var hasValue = Resources.TryGetValue("Primary", out object primaryColor);

if (hasValue)
{
    myLabel.TextColor = (Color)primaryColor;
}
```